# Product extra fee

Tags: product-quantity, extra, fee

I need to add a packaging fee for 2 specific products and I would like this packaging fee to be multiplied by the cart item quantity…

Any idea on how I can manage this?

Thank you in advance.

M

Answer (score 0):

Adding some code to help see what you want to make would be useful. Assuming you set this up in a Django web server, you would be able to save the product costs to variables and compare them to the product in the cart. For example:

```
cart = [] #we make cart empty list 
cart1item = 'Example1'
cart2item = 'Example2'
specificproduct1 = 'specific1'
specificproduct2 = 'specific2'

if specificproduct1 or specificproduct2 in cart:
      specificproduct1.append(card).len()
      specificproduct2.append(cart).len()
```

Best Of Luck!